# How can I specify index value order when calling SQL::Translator::Table's add_index function?

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

I am using DBIx::Class to create tables and their indexes and so calling [SQL::Translator::Table add_index()](http://search.cpan.org/~jrobinson/SQL-Translator-0.11007/lib/SQL/Translator/Schema/Table.pm#add_index) but I'd like to be able to specify a value order on some of the columns, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON mytable (
    username ASC,
    created  DESC
);
```

Is it possible to supply the 'ASC' and 'DESC' modifiers to add_table()?

If not, I suspect that this SQL would be inefficient:

```
SELECT text FROM mytable WHERE username = ? ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Any suggested work-around to reduce database overhead in this case? (I'm using MySql 5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently [SQL::Translator::Producer::MySQL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL%3a%3aTranslator%3a%3aProducer%3a%3aMySQL) (and even DBIx::Class itself I think) do not provide a way to do this.

However, according to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html), these index collations are currently ignored:

> An index_col_name specification can
>   end with ASC or DESC. These keywords
>   are permitted for future extensions
>   for specifying ascending or descending
>   index value storage. Currently, they
>   are parsed but ignored; index values
>   are always stored in ascending order.